# MS Graph - team create API returns 403 Forbidden error suddenly

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, access-token, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a singletenant Azure app and i have all the required permission for creating a MS team via app, and The API was working fine with multi-tenant App earlier, but same code is not working for singletenant app registered user; Please let me know if I am missing anything here;
I am using organization tenant uri in my authn and authz calls for single tenant.

Below Postman screenshot is the error response from graph API
[Error repsonse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wmLk.png)
[complete error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWwJT.png)

[API Permissions for MS Team create API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEpBT.png)

[decoded token with required permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qGlh.png)

Not able to create team since last 3 days.

[Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qaca.png)

[obo API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S8WA.png)

Comment: Could you include what authentication flow you used to get token?

Comment: Hi Sridevi, I am using ouath2 - onbehalf of  token- (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow  ) for token generation.

Comment: Could you confirm whether that user has Office 365 license assigned or not?

Comment: yes, they are able to access MS team app, create teams, and they are having work account with MS

Comment: ok, Thank you, is this anything to do with Azure app configuration? I have checked 'id_token' under 'Authentication'. This is valid correct? I have edited the description and added the screenshot of 'Authentication' panel

Comment: Those are needed if you are using **implicit** authentication flow to generate token. Could you include how you generated assertion value in on-behalf of flow?

Comment: I am invoking OAuth2.0 token API, for generating the token - https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa/oauth2/v2.0/token   And https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Client-tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize for authorization and using rest calls for both

Comment: If you are generating token from Postman, could you include those screenshots too by editing your question?

Comment: Hi Sridevi, added three screenshots from postman.

Comment: You are refreshing the access token, could you include how you got **refresh token**?

Comment: Added the screenshot to get the access token and refresh token, currently I dont have a expired code, so this is giving 400,.

Comment: You are using authorization code flow to get token not on-behalf flow

Comment: Hey Sridevi, Thanks, i am using obo flow in the code, in Postman was using auth code, Sorry for the misguide, but issue is same with both, I am getting forbidden error. I have updated the description as well.

Comment: but I am able access GET APis, i can get the teams for the user using same access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered one **single tenant** Azure AD application and granted **`Team.Create`** permission of **Delegated** type:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **on-behalf of** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: token
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to create team, I too got **same error** as you like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams

{
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName": "My Sample Team",
  "description": "My Sample Team’s Description"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> **Note:** While creating teams, **Microsoft 365** group will be created with same name.

In my case, the error occurred as creation of **Microsoft 365** groups is disabled for users in that specific tenant:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to enable creation of **Microsoft 365** groups option for users like this:

[image]

When I ran the graph query again by generating new token, I got below **response**:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams

{
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName": "My Sample Team",
  "description": "My Sample Team’s Description"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where new **Microsoft 365** group with same name created successfully:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sridevi,  This was the reason. Microsoft 365 groups was disabled .Thank you for your help. teams are getting created now.